# Android studio 2.2.2 jitpack dependency url not synced and getting depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

Tags: android, github, android-studio-2.2, jitpack

I have extracted .aar library as a library project using eclipse and using as submodule( only one classes jar containing this lib) in Android studio 2.2.2.

```
Note: currently I am creating a Mini Library Project using the support submodule project.I have synced with submodule to Mini Project and run project and saw output successfully. now, am converting main project as a library. I have removed application plugin and comment launcher in manifest and application id also.( In this MiniProject having two jars in libs folder, one for Ksoap, and another one jar.) 

GITHUB PART: then, I uploaded this library project to Github.

Jitpack PART: then, using git, I synced this git code into Jitpack repository and created dependency URL from Jitpack using public url.

Final: finally I have synced this library jitpack url into New Project. It could not synced. getting error like this..

Error:Module 'com.github.vh*******v:MyApp3:-SNAPSHOT' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar.
```

can anyone help to find the solution

Comment: Could you include a link to the github repository?